# What should I do if my question is correct but it gets downvotes?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, down-votes

Sometimes I get downvotes on a correct question asked by me. At present I have to delete them to stop reducing my reputation. Is there any way to stop people downvoting a question or to get a reason when anybody downvotes it so that I can repair the mistakes?

Comment: Leave a comment to ask why there were downvotes.

Comment: The best you can do is to add a comment under your question asking for why was your question downvoted. Rest is all in interest of the downvoter whether he/she adds a comment or not.

Comment: Keep deleting them, and you won't be able to ask questions at all.

Comment: @AndrewBarber sorry didn't get .

Comment: I can't see your downvoted questions so I can't advise you what to improve. Generally, leave a polite comment asking for the downvote reason and make sure your follow the [Stackoverflow Question Checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). If you think you are being serially down voted then see [what is serial downvoting and how does it affect me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: You can get blocked from asking questions. Getting regularly down voted then deleting your questions is one way that can happen.

Comment: @AndrewBarber what should i do to ignore unwanted down votes and what will i do. If my question is good but i am getting down vote on it ?
will commenting helps me in stopping further down vote ?

Comment: @keshu since most of us can't see your deleted posts, why don't you post the text of one of your questions and we can hwlelp you identify why you are getting downvotes

Comment: Its worth stopping assuming your question is good and you're getting downvotes because other people are wrong. I guess it might be true, but its unlikely

Comment: I you delete them, you also prevent anyone upvoting those questions.

Comment: If you want to "to ignore unwanted down votes" you have a big problem. Downvotes are there for a reason and by design there is no way to ignore them. You need to learn how to interact with community without causing downvotes, that's all. And by the way, have you ever seen "wanted downvotes"?

Comment: I'm not sure how someone has a "correct" question.

Comment: Everyone votes up or votes down for different reasons.  Some follow the guidance from SO, others use it more like a "Like" button, some use it to get even with people they feel are rude or are not accepting answers, and others use voting as a way to help 'their' answer look better.  Just learn to deal with it because there is nothing you can do about it other than ask "why the down votes"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What should i do if my question is correct but i get down votes on it?
>   Is their any way to stop down voting on a question [...]

Reconsider if it's really "correct". First and foremost, make sure you don't fit the downvote tooltip:

> This question does not show any research effort; it's unclear or not useful.

Second, check out the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/162730). If you pass most of those checks, then you probably will be getting more upvotes than downvotes.

If both of these fail, turn to chat or meta with specific examples and ask for help on how to improve your questions.

PS. Related to your question: don't delete your questions if it's possible to improve them by editing.

> Is their any way [...] to get a reason when anybody down votes?

Either a reflect on the question yourself using abovementioned checklist, or ask in a comment for explanations.

Comment: Thank that's what i am trying to ask because i found that this question can help many users :)

Answer (score 5):

Your thing is right! Some questions which are correct for the asker, are down voted. Not because people are hating the question or because the question is vague. But because the answerer would think that you have not searched for anything.

1. **Code that you're having troubles with:** The first thing that the answerer would go for, will be any code in your question. To make his mind! He would likely answer if the code you are posting is understandable by him. For me, a question in `ASP.NET Razor` would be preferable, and question in `PHP` would cause a trouble. But that doesn't mean I should downvote it.
2. **Search:** Then the person would start reading the question, if the question is for knowing how to write the response for ajax, the answerer would either **comment** or **downvote**.
3. **You should be on-topic:** You should have read on the stackoverflow.com's about page. The questions related to programming are welcomed there, any question not related to code would seem to be off-topic and would be downvoted!

What you should do, is to comment under the question and ask **What is wrong or missing in my question?** The people would tell you what they were hoping and what they got. So try to fulfil their demands. Like posting the sample code which you're having troubles with or try to show an image of the error or a reference. **Commenting** is the best way to know what the question lacks in. As even if you have 1 point, you can still comment on your post.

When a question doesnot show any research, then there is no need for that question. Stackoverflow recommends the users to **First search for an answer, if nothing helped! Let us help you**. You can also try the suggestions that you get while typing in the question input bar. You are more likely to find an answer there!

And there is no other reason or way, to stop getting downvoted, instead of just adding a few more details! :) Cheers,